# How to point a domain to my home server?

Tags: playframework, web-hosting

I'm completely new to web hosting, excuse my lack of knowledge.

I have purchased a domain at godaddy. I looked up my IP address and made the record point to it as such:

[image]

I am launching the server by generating an executable with "activator dist" - this generates an executable to start the server (alternative to using "activator start" since it is bugged on windows 7). The shell reports that it is listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000. The website renders on my browser when i go to 127.0.0.1:9000.

Now i'm obviously missing something, as when i go to mydomain.org the connection times out. What is there left to do?

Comment: It could be a problem with the godaddy settings, your router, your firewall, your server configuration! 127.0.0.1 is the localhost IP, so if you can see the website, then we can probably rule out your server. Try this to see if your router is allowing incoming connections ... http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: If you don't have a public static IP, domain name a bit useless. Your internet Provider will give you a new IP once in a while unless you bought their static IP plan. And you also need to port forward the public IP to the server IP.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 It says that it is closed - i'll look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a question for your home network setup. If you are using a Wifi router with firewall, you will most likely need to enable some kind of **port forwarding** to allow the world to access the process on your server.

Even more so, there may be software firewalls on the Operating System blocking the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a service http://www.dns2go.com you can change your IP address dynamically so you can host on your home server.